# AS3: Most efficient way to create a tinted copy of a BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, textures, bitmapdata

I have a `BitmapData` which is generated by `draw`ing a `DisplayObject`. I would like to create a pure white silhouette copy of that `BitmapData`. It seems there would be two approaches to do so:

1. Apply a `ColorTransform` to the `DisplayObject` and then have a new `BitmapData` with the same dimensions `draw` it.
2. Create a new `BitmapData`, then `copyPixels` the original, then apply a `ColorTransform` via `BitmapData.colorTransform`.

Neither `BitmapData` will be displayed inside a `Bitmap`, so applying a `ColorTransform` to that is not an option. They will instead be turned into a Starling `Texture`.

Which method would be more efficient? I would run some benchmarks myself, but I'm concerned the answer would be dependent on the size and complexity of the DisplayObject being drawn. Perhaps the `copyPixels` method would be better when the size is small and worse if it's large, and the `draw` method would be better if the DisplayObject to be drawn is simple and worse if it's complex. Also, are the copyPixels and BitmapData.colorTransform methods done on the GPU? If so, I suppose that would tilt things in their favor.

Comment: You can apply **ColorMatrixFilter** http://doc.starling-framework.org/v2.3/starling/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html to **Starling** object (**Image** or **Sprite**). Is that not an option?

Comment: Yes, but that would increase my number of draw calls, wouldn't it? But then again, I suppose reducing your draw calls is not the be-all and end-all of optimization.

Comment: Indeed, it will. Then, a use of another **Texture** from another **BitmapData** will increase it all the same (unless you are into runtime atlases). So, it is extra memory (from extra **BitmapData** and extra **Texture**) vs some processing power to apply a filter.

Comment: For step **(2)**, You could also try bitmapData's **threshold** or **paletteMap** options... Personally I'd just use a `for` loop to apply colour effects, for that you can also use with **lock** and **unlock** option for faster processing. How efficient does your _"efficient"_ need to be?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying VC.One. BitmapData.colorTransform is essentially just doing getPixel32, applying the colorTransform ARGB multipliers and offets, then doing setPixel32 for every pixel in the BitmapData. I might as well just setPixel everything to 0xffffff in a loop, which would leave the alpha unchanged.

Comment: I've tried iterating through each pixel, and that method is around 10 times slower than copyPixels + colorTransform. I also tried to copyChannel just the source alpha onto a plain white BitmapData, and that was still slower. It looks like copyPixels + colorTransform is king.

Comment: You want `newBMDBytes = getPixels32(olderBMD)` not `getPixel`... when you have them, set `.position` of bytes to zero then use `For` or `While` loop. Check colour by `readUnsignedInt` ( then `if( (color << 24) == 0)` you have transparent (just ignore) `else` go back **four** bytes with `newBMDBytes.position -= 4;` and overwrite value `newBMDBytes.writeUnsignedInt (0xFFFFFFFF);` continue until bytes ending...

Comment: I tested the ByteArray method, and surprisingly it's still slower! Edited my answer with my results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some benchmarks, and in the best possible scenario for the draw method, where the `DisplayObject` to be drawn was simply a colored rectangle, draw was always faster than copyPixels by around 33%, regardless of size. Then I tried using some complex `DisplayObject`s with lots of shapes inside, and in those cases, draw was 300% to 400% slower. So the answer is "it depends". But I have to say, using the draw method has an upside potential of a 33% speed increase at most, but an enormous downside potential if the `DisplayObject` is complex.

I did some additional testing of the copyPixels/colorTransform method against the getPixels/setPixels method, and remarkably the getPixels/setPixels method was 20x slower! Here is my copyPixels method:

```
var start_time:int = getTimer();
var s1:S1 = new S1(); //S1 is simply a 100x100 red circle
var bmd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(s1.width,s1.height,true,0x00000000);
bmd1.drawWithQuality(s1,null,null,null,null,false,StageQuality.HIGH);
var bmd2:BitmapData;
var sourceRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,bmd1.width,bmd1.height);
var point00:Point = new Point();
var colorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,255,255,255,0);
var w:uint = bmd1.width,
    h:uint = bmd1.height,
    pixelHex:uint,
    pixelAlpha:uint;
var ba:ByteArray;
for (var i:uint=0; i<1000; i++) {
    bmd2 = new BitmapData(w,h,true,0x00000000);
    bmd2.copyPixels(bmd1,sourceRect,point00);
    bmd2.colorTransform(sourceRect,colorTransform);
}
trace("execution time: ", getTimer()-start_time); //execution time:  74
```

And here is my getPixels method for loop:

```
for (var i:uint=0; i<1000; i++) {
    ba = bmd1.getPixels(sourceRect);
    ba.position = 0;
    while (ba.bytesAvailable > 0) {
        pixelHex = ba.readUnsignedInt();
        pixelAlpha = pixelHex >>> 24;
        if (pixelAlpha > 0) {
            ba.position -= 4;
            ba.writeUnsignedInt((pixelAlpha<<24)|0xffffff);
        }
    }
    ba.position = 0;
    bmd2 = new BitmapData(w,h,true,0x00000000);
    bmd2.setPixels(sourceRect,ba);
}
trace("execution time: ", getTimer()-start_time); //execution time:  1349
```

Comment: Interesting results. I'll try my own within 24 hrs. Does having `cacheAsBitmap` on the _"complex DisplayObjects with lots of shapes inside"_ before any draw/copyPixels command help in any way? Also earlier I confused your `copyPixels` with `getPixels` (gives bytearray to `For` loop with).